# Context Menu items command binding WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, command, contextmenu

I know this question has been asked many times in different ways in many websites and also in StackOverFlow but all the answers I found are not helping me ot to be precise I am not able to understand them and implement in my application. So I thought of putting some code from my application so that you people can help me better.

Problem Statement : I am using a WPF DataGrid. I have added a **Context Menu** and I have 3 options Cut,Copy,Paste. I am using MVVM for development. I want to DataBind these options to Commands in my ViewModel. But I am unable to do the same. The context menu options are not getting data bound at all !!!

This is my Grid Code in XAML :

```
<custom:DataGrid  
      x:Name="DataGrid_Standard"   
      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"   
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                                           
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"   
      Background="Transparent"
      ItemsSource="{Binding FullGridData}" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource defaultRowStyle}"
      ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DefaultColumnHeaderStyle}"                         
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

Then I have a ContextMenu and a Style for Header Element

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="columnHeaderMenu">
   <MenuItem Command="{Binding CutCommand}"
             Header="Test" />
   <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
   <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
</ContextMenu>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DefaultColumnHeaderStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource columnHeaderMenu}" >
</Style>
```

This line goes in my constructor

```
public Window1()
{            
   this.DataContext = new AppData();
}
```

This code goes in my AppData class:

```
public class AppData  
{ 
    private IList<GridData> fullGridData = new ObservableCollection<GridData>();<br> 
    public IList<GridData> FullGridData
    {
        get { return fullGridData; }
        set { fullGridData = value; }
    }

    private DelegateCommand<object> cutCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<object> CutCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (cutCommand == null)
            {
                cutCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(CutColumn);
            }
            return cutCommand;
        }
    }

    private void CutColumn(object obj)
    {
        //some code goes here
    }   
}
```

** I want to know exactly where am I doing wrong?? Why is the DataBinding not happening??
Please help me regarding this. Please provide me the sample code or modification in my present code from which I can achieve it. **

Answer (score 2):

Something in your code (or the version of WPF being used at the time(?)) is overcomplicating things. I am able to bind such as

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Name="myGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyItem}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteItem}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Where the command is setup like this:

```
VM.DeleteItem 
     = new OperationCommand((o) => MessageBox.Show("Delete Me"),
                            (o) => (myGrid.SelectedItem as Order)?.InProgress == false );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The command bindings stopped working once I moved them to the ViewModel from code behind. And in the viewmodel I had to change my ICommand from RoutedCommand to DelegateCommand. I was able to get it working in the following way -

Add Opened eventhandler to your context menu -

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="columnHeaderMenu" Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Header="Test" />
    <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

In the code behind, you would assign your ViewModel to the context menu's DataContext -

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu menu = sender as ContextMenu;
    menu.DataContext = _vm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually instantiate my view model as static resource in my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Namespace.MySampleView" ...> 
    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <viewModels:MySampleViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" /> 
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you can easily reference any property of your view model even if the current binding context is not the view model:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="columnHeaderMenu">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

For more information, have a look at my article [Recommendations and best practices for implementing MVVM and XAML/.NET applications](http://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/).

Comment: This will create a new instance of the ViewModel that does not match the one that is binded to the window!

Answer (score 0):

```
<MenuItem Header="Cut" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.CutCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options.
Note: the code samples I added here a similar, but not same as your samples.

Move the definition of the ContextMenu inside the DataGrid defintion as follows:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid
   x:Name="DataGrid_Standard"
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
   Background="Transparent" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding FullGridData}" 
   ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DefaultColumnHeaderStyle}">
   <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Header="Test" />
           <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
           <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
       </ContextMenu>
   </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
```

Or better add a CommandReference to your Resources and set the Command in the MenuItem to a StaticResource as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:CommandReference x:Key="MyCutCommandReference" Command="{Binding CutCommand}" />

    <ContextMenu x:Key="columnHeaderMenu">
        <MenuItem Command="{StaticResource MyCutCommandReference}" Header="Test" />
        <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
    </ContextMenu>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DefaultColumnHeaderStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource columnHeaderMenu}" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<WpfToolkit:DataGrid
   x:Name="DataGrid_Standard"
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
   Background="Transparent" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding FullGridData}" 
   ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DefaultColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
```

Comment: I am using your second solution since I want context menu only for header.Actually now the commands are getting associated but my menu-item is disabled. I am using DelegateCommand class for binding. Its really strange Why is my menu-item disabled??

Comment: It worked for me, but I am not sure what implementation of DelegateCommand you are using; look at the second paramater that controls whether the command is enabled or not.  I added a sample here:

cutCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(CutColumn, CanCutCommand);

private bool CanCutCommand(object obj)
{
   return true;
}

Comment: I am using the DelegateCommand available in mvvm toolkit from codeplex. I have seen some websites in which they say its bug. The links are as follows : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/421816/wpf-command-based-context-menu-item-initially-disabled                http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7bd75a7c-eab4-4f3a-967b-94a9534a7455