# Command binding not working in a dynamic MVVM Context Menu

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, contextmenu

I am new to WPF. Like many others, I am trying to bind a `ContextMenu` to an `ObservableCollection` to create a dynamic context menu. 
Everything works except binding the `Command` property to the `TheCommand` property of the `MenuItemViewModel` class, that represents the menu item. The command is not fired. What am I doing wrong?

To start from the beginning, the `ContextMenu` is a child of the `Image` and is shown when the mouse is over the `Image`.

```
 <Image.ContextMenu >
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ContextMenu}"
```

where the empty ContextMenu is defined as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MenuItemViewModelCollection x:Key="ContextMenu">
    </local:MenuItemViewModelCollection>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Command"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},
                                    Path=DataContext.TheCommand}"/>
              <!--  Value="{Binding Path=TheCommand}" /> I tried this too -->

            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

The `TheCommand` property is defined below:

```cs
public class MenuItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       //...
       public ICommand TheCommand
       {
             //...
       }
}
```

Comment: What does your `MenuItemViewModelCollection` class look like? And are the menu items showing up correctly?

Answer (score 6):

DataContext on ContextMenus can be weird, I bet if you look in the output window in Visual Studio when debugging that there will be a binding error for TheCommand not being found. Try the following:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.TheCommand}"/>
```

This will use the DataContext of the element that the ContextMenu is launched from, not the context menu itself.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to fix and the tip on Output window is very helpful. But  I am not able to understand the hierarchy in which the DataContext is picked up. Because in my case it was picking up the content like this
`Content="{Binding Heading}"`
but it was not able to pick up the command
`Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand}"`

So I had to use
`Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand}"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`Value="{TemplateBinding TheCommand}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer for the following question -

[Context Menu items command binding WPF using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837557/context-menu-items-command-binding-wpf-using-mvvm/31706990#31706990)

Hope it helps!